# finding the element beside a specified element using prolog

Tags: prolog

the query given is

```
beside(Next,Beside,[a,b,c,d]).

Next=a, Beside=b;

Next=b, Beside=c;

Next=c, Beside=d;
```

the rule should be true if the elements x,y is beside each other.

Mine was only able to give the first answer, `Next=a, Beside=b` but not the rest.

so how can i get it to provide all the answers?

Answer (score 2):

append does the job :

```
beside(Next, Beside, L) :-
    append(_, [Next, Beside | _], L).
```